# Crystal reports crosstab customization

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I will try to explain my problem as simple as I can.

I would like to have a crosstab in my report for the questions/answers of a questionnaire. Rows for the questions, columns for the answers and in every cell the sum of the answers.

However, every question has its own group of answer and I would like something like

```
                       Very     So an So  Don't Ask
How happy are you?      10          9        1        
                      Love it      Nah    It's ok
Do you like rain?       1           3        1
```

The number represent how many people answered Very or Love it or..you get the point.

What I need is to know if this is possible and if anyone can point out some guidelines to do that!Thank you in advance!

EDIT: (hope this helps) I have a FeedbackT table, and the AnswerT that contains some anwers that don't concern me right now.The AnswerT table is connected with the Answer2T table (I know, it's a mess) and this table is connected with the ActualAnswerT which contains the answers (very low, low, medium...) and another table QuestionQroupT that contains some info about the group that the answers belong to.

The ActualAnswerT contains as many rows as the people who have taken a questionnaire. If 5 people answered a questionnaire, for Question 'A' I could have 3 'Low', 2 'High' from AnswerGroup1, for Question 'B' I could have 1 'No', 3 'Yes', 1 'I don't know' from AnswerGroup2 and so on..

Comment: If you have limited amount of possible answers (eg 3), then it is better (and simpler) to use 'normal' report and aggregates (of formulas) for result display.

Comment: If you have your questions stored with the group type and each group type has its own headers defined then you can use `Group Expert` to format your report. Other alternative could be to use `Sub-Reports`. But nothing can be said without looking at the source data structure.

Comment: @Arvo I know and I already did that but I was asked to customize it

Comment: @haraman The questions are not qrouped in any way. The answers may be. I don't know if your suggestion will work with the answers but I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: It may be achievable via answer grouping but again depends on your database organization. If you need any help further, edit your question and include your table structure along with relationships of related tables and columns.

Comment: I try it....and it's not working.. I am not allowed to share any DB information. 
What I can tell you is that each group of answers has a category. For example HappyCat[Very, So and So, Dont Ask] etc. in the DB level.

Comment: I would tend to agree with @haraman in that we need your data, or a solid mockup.. like 10 rows of it [5 rows of each 'question'].

Comment: If questions are less then try to create new crosstab for every question and place all one by one.....i hope it works...give it a try

Comment: Do all answer groups contain 3 entries? Are these ordered? If yes, then you can create pivot query in SQL, returning three columns for answer group and link this query to answer - hard to explain further without seeing your data. It is always better [for Crystal Reports] to prepare data at SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a union query in the order of `question, answer1, answer2, answer3` then you'd have a consistent virtual table you can create a cross tab from.